# tinymce Не работает ввод текста

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Здравствуйте. Подключила редактор tinymce.
В head:

```
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=lyvb5rq4yt96armwsnztc33l17n2xeo14b6s41qbvjaiqgvx"></script>
```

В body:

```
<form action=".?action=<?php echo $results['formAction']?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title">
    <textarea placeholder="Article" name="content" rows="25" cols="100"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="datePublication" value="<?php echo strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")); ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Send">
    <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
</form>
```

Сам скрипт:

```
    <script>
            tinymce.init({
                selector: 'textarea',
                height: 300,
                menubar: false,
                plugins: [
                    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
                    'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
                    'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code'
                ],
                toolbar: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
                content_css: [
                    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
                    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css']
            });
</script>
```

Но само окно ввода не дает вводить текст и делать вообще какие-либо манипуляции. В чем может быть дело? Консоль без ошибок

Comment: В консоль браузера загляните. Какие ошибки и предупреждения javascript там есть?

Comment: Консоль чистая без ошибок